# Jquery click() function not recognising when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple JavaScript operation which is just not working. I'm using the twitter-bootstrap CSS, and am attempting to implement the close of the close message box. I have my code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/YQgpe/

HTML

```
<div class = "alert-message success"  id = "message_1">
    <a class = "close" href = "#">x</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function hideSomething(which_thing) 
{
    $(which_thing).hide();
}

$(".close").click(function() 
{
    hideSomething("#" + $(this).parent().attr("id"));
});
```

Essentially I want the same "close" class of link to hide the div when clicked - hence the request for the parent id. But even though jslint tells me my code is valid - it still doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Evidently I was simply using jsfiddle incorrectly. The code doesn't work within my site so the error must be something else... the search continues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, I just removed the js lint and it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/YQgpe/15/

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing and it worked :)  Ps: also a good idea to use "return false;" to prevent the link href to be executed.

Comment: Yeah, `return false` from the anchor `click` handler stops its default behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on return false - I'll be putting that to use.

Answer (score 4):

It works if you remove `jQueryLint (edge)` as library: http://jsfiddle.net/YQgpe/10/

However, your code can be simplified to:

```
$(".close").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

You already have a reference to the parent, there is not need to search for it *again* via its ID.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I know I'm using a bit of a round about way of doing this but I'm attempting to implement MVC within my js - still sorting out exactly what that means.